# Stuff on the walls of a Starfleet holding cell

Tags: star-trek

Here is a picture of a Starfleet holding cell from the episode *TNG: The Hunted*

What are the various rectangular and octagonal things on the walls?   And what is the purpose of the red stripe on some of them, and the bed?

[image]

Comment: Out of universe the answer is 'a bunch of kitbashed futuristic-looking crap, intended to make it look like a cell *in spaaaaace*...'

Comment: Greebles.  They make it look like science fiction, instead of just a walk-in closet with an oddly shaped door.

Comment: Out-of-universe I imagine it was just for visual effect as others have said, in-universe the only time I can think of where any part of the wall had a function was in "I, Borg" when they modified a bit of it to give Hugh a way to draw energy (image [here](https://tng.trekcore.com/gallery/albums/s5/5x23/iborg214.jpg)). So I guess you could imagine they were all removable covers for components that could be easily modified to become devices that would serve the needs of different prisoners (maybe some sections could be turned into limited-use replicators, for example).

Comment: Since it's grey-on-grey, I can imagine their workspace H&S team required the edge of the bed to be marked so it would be harder to run into by accident. :)

Comment: Extrapolation on my part, but the purpose of the bed might be to sleep on? :D

Comment: This is actually S3:E11 - "The Hunted" - the man in the cell is Roga Danar - https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Hunted_(episode) (the image above is actually in the Memory Alpha article for the episode :) )

Comment: Har de Har, @Silly. In case anyone didn't get it, I'm asking about the red stripe on the bed.     NKCampbell, I stand corrected.

Comment: One of them probably pulls out to become a toilet.

Comment: There's a washbasin and a mirror on the left of the cell.  I presume the pull out toilet is there too.    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uh2fe1wk7sM

Comment: Almost the same question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/247030/what-was-the-gaudily-coloured-equipment-on-the-enterprises-corridor-walls-in-st?rq=1

Comment: I could tell you, but my answer would be meaningless to someone from the 21st century - like explaining Blockchain to a caveman.

Comment: @DavidW if that's the case, the bed is delineated by the blue mattress on top. It doesn't need a red painted stripe that's almost not visible as you walk up to it.